# How to help Simplify with conjugates without using ComplexExpand

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I have a seemingly simple simplification involving conjugates:

```
$Assumptions = Element[{a}, Reals];
FullSimplify[ x E^(I a) + Conjugate[x] E^(-I a)]
```

which merely outputs this,

```
E^(-I a) (E^(2 I a) x + Conjugate[x])
```

I would have expected the expression above to simplify to

```
2 Re[x E^(I a)]
```

In order to use ComplexExpand, one needs to explicitly convert every cplx variable into either Cartesian or polar form, which causes quite some extra labour:

```
expr = x E^(I a) + Conjugate[x] E^(-I a);
repToCart = {x -> xRE + I xIM};
repToCplx = {xRE -> Re[x], xIM -> Im[x]};
$Assumptions = Element[{a, xRE, xIM}, Reals];
Output = FullSimplify[expr /. repToCart] /. repToCplx
```

outputs this:

```
2 Cos[a] Re[x] - 2 Im[x] Sin[a]
```

This is indeed the same as this:

```
2 Re[x E^(I a)]
```

But it is

1. More complicated
2. Required quite some extra steps

Any tips on how to speed up the workflow here would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You can get the second expression with `ComplexExpand[x E^(I a) + Conjugate[x] E^(-I a), {x}, 
 TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not aware of this wonderful shortcut ! This helps a lot. I would even have marked this comment as an accepted answer if it were an answer.

Comment: Go ahead and post an answer yourself then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up to the comment of b.gates.you.know.what, I think that is the most useful answer.

```
ComplexExpand[x E^(I a) + Conjugate[x] E^(-I a), {x},   TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]
```

This approach spares the user to write replacement rules back and forth.
The answer from Alexei Boulbitch is also useful, but not much different than the replacement rules I mentioned in my post.

Thanks to all.
Massimo

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand, why not to use `ComplexExpand]`. However, if not, try this:

```
expr = x E^(I a) + Conjugate[x] E^(-I a) /. x -> z + I*t;


Simplify[expr // ExpToTrig, {a, z, t} \[Element] Reals] /. {z -> 
   Re[x], t -> Im[x]}

(*   2 Cos[a] Re[x] - 2 Im[x] Sin[a] *)
```

Have fun!